# Only replace string in sql when not adjacent to other characters

Tags: sql, replace

I'm using MSSQL 2008 to replace the values in certain columns. My current query is:

```
UPDATE table  
SET name = replace(name, 'old', 'new')
```

I would like to know if it is possible to only replace 'old' by 'new' when 'old' is not adjacent to other characters. That is: only when it actually occurs as 'old' 
 This would ensure that e.g. 'bold' does not become 'bnew'

Currently I'm retrieving results via JDBC, splitting the string at the delimiter (,) and then checking if the string equals'old'. If so I want to replace with 'new'. It takes a long time to retrieve all the results and send them back, so **if this is possible by only sending an SQL-statement containg 'old' & 'new' that would be great!**

Records where it should be replaced:

- 'old , blabla blabla, bla'
- 'blabla, old, blabla'
- 'blabla, bla old, blabla'
- 'blabla, blabla, old'
- 'blabla, bla old bla'

Records where it shouldn't be replaced:

- 'blaold, blabla'
- 'blabla, oldbla'

Comment: What word delimiters do you have? Just spaces and start of string/ end of string or also punctuation?

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm currently doing this in Java (matching with regex, replacing and sending back to the DB) but it takes a lot of time. I was wondering how to do this in SQL, but I'm not that familiar with its syntax

Comment: @MartinSmith comma's are used as delimiters.

Comment: If you are storing comma delimited values in a single column and having problems as you need to split them apart into their constituent elements in the database than that would indicate a design problem to me. If these words were stored in another table with one row per word the update would be trivial.

Comment: @MartinSmith You are right about the design problem. Unfortunately this db has been given to me as is, I'm going to go with the solution James proposd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spaces in your clauses.

UPDATE [YourTable]
SET    name = replace(name, ' old ', 'new')
WHERE  name = ' old '

Comment: I actually changed the values so that they are always preceded and followed by a space. Now I can use this solution.